# Referring to a constant from library, twincat 3

Tags: reference, twincat

Im trying to accomplish a twincat 3 library which does things using global constants defined in the main project, like creating arrays the size of those constants and cycling trough them. However I've been unsuccessful and I wonder if this can be done. I just get this error "Error 4 Border 'cPassedConstant' of array is no constant value" when I try to build the main project. The error comes from the array defined in the library.

I've tried making a GVL with a constant of the same name to the library and then setting the "external implementation" property true but that does not help.

My goal here is to make a IO management library with filtering and such. And then I could just add it to the main project and define some constants like "cDigitalIputsCount","cAnalogInputCount" and so on.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Arrays that use constants are possible even if constant is in library. Can you please provide some code, with clear separation what is in the library and what is in the other project?

Comment: I specifically want so that the constant is defined in the main project and it is used by the library. Lets say I want to create a system with for example 10 analog IOs.

Comment: ... I would then include my IO library to the main project, define a global constant cAINs: UINT := 10; and then in MAIN, I would call PRG_IO POU which is in the library. In PRG_IO there would be an ARRAY[1..cAINs] of FB_AnalogIn which would get executed in a for loop. Also in the library there would be a function F_GetAnalogIn which would get the filtered/scaled AI value for the FB. Point being that I could easily create a IO system of variable number of IOs just by including the library, defining a few constants and calling PRG_IO. Do you now understand?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get along with the new ARRAY[*] feature instead, although it is still very limited. There is no other way than to define the constant in the library.

The library concept is the same as in other environments. A library provides you reusable components. Your main project depends on the library and not the other way around. Therefore your library cannot know a thing about the project where it is used.

A confusing thing in TwinCat3 is, that you can build projects successful with programming errors inside. The TwinCat3 compiler allows broken code inside a project as long as it is not called. Therefore when you ship libraries you should always use "Check all objects".

Answer (score 1):

You should check Beckhoff's feature called [Parameter List](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3470837515.html&id=). By adding a parameter list to the library project, you can re-define library constants in the project that uses the library. The definition happens in the library manager.

*Image from Beckhoff's site:*
[image]

I think that should do it. Of course, the other option is to use the `ARRAY[*]` option, which is awesome too (for a PLC programming world). The problem with parameter lists is that it is a project-wide re-definition. Using the `ARRAY[*]` allows the size be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a variable length ARRAY[*], as explained in the link below (and also in the Beckhoff/Infosys, section DataTypes/Array).

The point is that you should declare the ARRAY[1..cAINs] of FB_AnalogIO in your main program (it knows the FB_AnalogIO from your analog library and can declare it with a constant size).

The PRG_IO should then be changed to either a function or function block, so that it accepts the ARRAY[*] as a VAR_IN_OUT without knowing the exact size.

https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/iec-61131-3-arrays-with-variable-length/

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of such feature. Ill look into that.